# Has it been proven the fine-structure constant (FSC) changes with time?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, renormalization, big-bang, physical-constants

I have heard this claimed over and over, even that the FSC was 1 at the Big Bang.  Is there any actual consensus among scientists that this is so?

Answer (score 0):

The fine structure constant depends on the energetic scale, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Variation_with_energy_scale. This means that near the big bang, where the energetic scale was way higher than nowadays, the fine structure constant was higher. The fact that it was higher and not lower comes from the [beta function of QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics)). As a counter-example, since the beta function of QCD is negative, for higher energies, the coupling decreases.

Comment: Is there any actual data that shows the constant is different elsewhere in the universe?

Comment: The energetic scale of the universe depends globally on the time parameter. But locally, such as in the LHC experiments, you can have a higher energetic scale than the global one.  Every single experiment in the LHC has confirmed the running of coupling constants. For example, you have https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06631, which gives you an experiment showing this very running for QED. (but it is not at the LHC)

Comment: Is there a formula to calculate FSC based on energy?

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics)#Quantum_electrodynamics

Comment: Wouldn't imply the elementary charge, or even the masses of particles vary as well?

Comment: It is true that the elementary charge and the mass *appear* to vary mathematically, but for the mass, we just adjust the theory so that the physical mass is the pole of the full propagator. For the charge, it gives the structure constant when squared (up to a factor $4\pi$).

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: This is not what is normally meant by time variation of $α$, and not, I think, what OP was asking about. There is no evidence of a change in $α$ over cosmological time scales in the usual sense (the kind of change that wouldn't also show up in a present-day experiment).

Comment: @benrg I completely agree with you that OP's point was more along the lines of "what is $\alpha$ varies from today to tomorrow". But OP mentioned the Bigbang si I dived into this breach.

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke I am afraid that the elaboration of such a point is the subject of entire lectures...